# Kivy-Image only centered some of the time at run time

Tags: image, python-3.x, kivy, grid-layout, kivy-language

i have a GridLayout with a Button and an image to display inside the Button. when i run my app the Image in the button sometimes centers and sometimes it don't. why? i believe it should always be centered.

.kv file:

```
MyLayout:
    cols: 2                
    height: self.minimum_height
    pos: root.pos

    Button:
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.parent.width/2
        Image:
            source: 'Images/employee/userprofile.png'
            size: self.parent.size
            center_x: self.parent.center_x
            center_y: self.parent.center_y
```

the following image is what I expect every time:

[image]

this is what I get sometimes:
[image]

Comment: Do you want to resize the image? Should it expand and fill the entire button?

Comment: I added screen shots of what I mean. basically at run time I get either of those result when I should(I think) get the first result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common issue with alias properties like `center_x`, `right`, `top`, etc. Setting them in kv doesn't automatically bind to the size of the widget (adding that to kivy is not as trivial as it sounds), so while the image is positionned correctly at first, if it's resized after, then the position is not updated, because the parent's pos didn't change, only the children's size! As luck would have it, in such situation, it's not uncommon to have code that seems to work half of the time, depending on the timing of dispatching in that particular run.

Anyway, the solution is quite simple, explicitly reference the children's size in the bindings, so the expression is recomputed every time it changes.

```
        center_x: self.width and self.parent.center_x
        center_y: self.height and self.parent.center_y
```